# Flash video doesn't work after upgrade to 11.10

Tags: 11.10, video, flash

I've found that after upgrading to 11.10 (32 bit), I can no longer watch streaming flash video on sites such as Ustream or Justin.tv.  I've spent the last several hours installing this package and uninstalling that package, and purging everything flash-related and starting over, to no avail.  I was curious if anybody else has run into similar issues and found a fix.

I'm running an NVIDIA card, and I've tried both sets of drivers available.

Comment: I think it's particularly pathetic that an upgrade of Ubuntu (nowaways) still manages to break flash support.

Answer (score 2):

I got tired of the adobe-flashplugin package failing on me so I did it manually.

Download the flash plugin from the [adobe website](http://get.adobe.com/fr/flashplayer/otherversions/). Pick the 64 bit, `.tar.gz` version. Take the `libflashplayer.so` file from that archive and move it:

`sudo mv libflashplayer.so /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins`.

Make sure it is executable:

`sudo chmod +x /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libflashplayer.so`

Screw the buggy installers.

Pros : It's gonna work.

Cons : It won't update automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Go to firefox ads on (Edit -> preferences -> manage ads on) and then install plugin flash-aid. Install **stable flash version** instead of **beta**. It worked for me.